# Android API from the linux layer

Tags: android, api, shell

I'm looking to know if one can use the SMS/MMS api from the linux layer, ie: in a shell/perl/python script for ex.

More extensively, is it possible to use the full android API from such a script/program, with just an import/include of android lib ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found this : http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/

I allows what I asked for, scripting Android from regular scripts (ie: not an Android App).

An example of a SMS script can be found here : https://github.com/s7ephen/Blowfish-SMS